# Hidding UIText in Unity 4.6

Tags: user-interface, text, unity-game-engine

I want in my game after a couple seconds that my UIText dissepears, so I mean not the GUIText component but the new UIText in Unity 4.6

Thanks
Ruben

Answer (score 0):

First of all,make sure to include this:

```
using UnityEngine.UI;
```

Then you can initialize your text:

```
public Text exampleText;
```

Then to turn the text off you can use:

```
exampleText.text = "";
```